# level of variable?

Tags: terminology, descriptive-statistics

I was looking at [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat/)

What does the level of a variable mean? I can only think of categorical variables with 2 values, like gender. Is there continuous variables with only 2 levels?

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Comment: Here's the link. [link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat/) I was wondering if number of levels of a variable means the number of values it could take.

Comment: Please quote the relevant part(s) in your question (crediting the author if identifiable)

Answer (score 1):

In general "level" could mean any of several different things.

However, the context is sufficient to identify the intent here.

In phrases such as "1 IV with 2 levels (independent groups)" the independent variable is a grouping variable which take two values, indicating two independent groups.

For example:

```
 DV    IV
score gender
 37     1
 45     1
 22     1
 39     2
 32     2
 28     2
```

Here 1=female, 2=male, say, making a categorical variable taking two different possible values.